# Decoding function in c# corrresponding to base64_encode function in php

Tags: c#

I need to fetch data from a table the corresponding column data in encoded in **base64_encode** fromat from a php.I need to fetch the data and decode that in the C# language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
byte[] blob = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Text);
```